# Conditional clause in the future

Tags: conditional-constructions, future-tense

Please consider this context:

- we are on Day 0
- there is a meeting on Day 4
- I am leaving the country for 15 days at some time between Day 2 and Day 5

Is the following sentence correct?

**"If I haven't left the country already, I will attend the meeting."**

Please consider the verb tense and the choice between already/yet.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! And thanks for a very clear question.

Comment: @Nathan, thanks for the edition. I don't know why I wrote that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is fine. The present perfect is correct, and although both *already* and *yet* would work here, *already* is to be preferred because it's slightly less likely to be misparsed as referring to today, Day 0.

You might consider moving *already* after *haven't*. It's fine where it is, but it's got just a hair more emphatic rhythm right before *left*, which is the word you really want to stress:

```
If I haven't  already  left  the country  
            da-boomty BOOMP  da-boomty
```